# Self-Factorial Number

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Self-factorial number is the number where its digits' factorials summation is equal to the number itself. But there are only a few amount of them. For example;

$1=1!$

$2=2!$

$145= 1!+4!+5!$

So what is the fourth self-factorial number? How about fifth?

Comment: Are we using base ten?

Comment: @Ankoganit of course :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A self-factorial number can have no more than 7 digits. Proof:
Suppose it has $n$ digits. Then the sum of the factorials of the digits is at most
$$
9! \cdot n = 362880n
$$
whereas the number itself is at least
$$
10^{n-1}.
$$
For $n \ge 8$, $10^{n-1} > 362880n$ so these two cannot be equal.

So it remains that we check all numbers with up to $7$ digits.
A brute-force search checking $1$ to $9999999$ finds that the only solutions are

> 1, 2, 145, 40585.

Comment: i like this one, thanks for showing that it is not possible to have more than 4 numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Its

> 40585. They are [factorians-A014080](https://oeis.org/A014080). And no there is no fifth. [Reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorion)

Comment: lol I did not know it was defined :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Java program to find a solution by brute-force. I found

> 40585

as a fourth number.

The fifth number should have a ton of digits. I'm still searching.

EDIT: it looks like there is not a fifth one.

Comment: It's a Java program. It'll take it some time to count to 5.